# Error : HTML + jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, knockout.js

I am error for open popap jQuery:

**1. Botón Código HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAddCentrocosto" value="AddCentrocosto" onclick="$parent.openAddCentrocosto">Agregar Centro Costos</button>
```

**2. Popap HTML**

```
<div class="panel-heading" id="dialogAddCentrocosto" title="Centro de Costos..."> 
        <table>          
            <tr>
                <td><label>Costo : </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="nCosto" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Observaciones : </label></td>
                <td><textarea rows="5" id="strObservacionDistribucion"   class="form-control" name="strObservacionDistribucion"></textarea></td>    
            </tr>

        </table>
</div>
```

**3. Jquery**

```
self.openAddCentrocosto = function () {
            tr = jQuery('#btnAddCentrocosto').parent().parent();
            jQuery('#Distribucion').val(jQuery('td[data-bind="text: 
            jQuery('#nCosto').val('');
            jQuery('#nImpuestoDistribucion').val('18');
            //jQuery('#nTotalDistribucion').val('');
            jQuery('#dialogAddCentrocosto').dialog('open');
        }
```

**4. Mensaje de error**
When clicking on the button I should raise the popap, but it is not done and it shows me the following error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $parent is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

***I am adding knockout.js since within a field of the framework exactly a for each if the call works, but the button I require it outside so that it does not repeat as many lines as the detail.***

**Please if anyone can help me with this error, thank you very much.**

Comment: What does this question have to do with [tag:knockout.js]?

Comment: ***I am adding knockout.js since within a field of the framework exactly a for each if the call works, but the button I require it outside so that it does not repeat as many lines as the detail.***

Comment: Sorry, I am having too tough of a time trying to understand what you want to say.

Answer (score 1):

In your `onclick` attribute you've set `$parent.openAddCentrocosto`, yet `$parent` is not defined at the global scope, where it would need to be for this to work.

There's two solutions. Firstly you could move `$parent` to a global scope. Secondly you could get rid of the `onclick` attribute and use jQuery to hook up the event. This will fix the issue by proxy, so long as you declare `$parent` within the `document.ready` scope.

The latter of these solutions, is by far the better. `on*` attributes are now very outdated and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: #Rory McCrossan, Do you have any reference links? I do not have the syntax clear.